# Virtual hosts & xampp

Tags: xampp, virtual-host

Hi Wonder if anyone can help.

I have trying to get virtual hosts working on a local installation of xampp with not much success for the last few hours, all the numerous examples I have tried just seem to point to the same thing - it looks pretty simple, set hosts & add into httpd-vhosts.

The hosts file part seems to be working but I'm unsure about the virtual host part.

The problem is it just loads up the xampp welcome page.

Ideally I want to set up so the virtual hosts point to a mapped drive, but for the moment I'd be happy with just pointing to a folder in the htdocs !

Is there a way to check that my virtual hosts part is working ?

Thanks

MRO

Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/testdomain"
    ServerName www.testdomain.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" combined
    
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

## localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
#::1             localhost
```

## virtual hosts

127.0.0.1 www.testdomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the # from this lines

## NameVirtualHost *:80

and

### ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost

Change www.dummy-host.localhost to www.testdomain.com

Then restart xampp.

I believe you would also need to add this to your hosts

127.0.0.1 www.testdomain.com